# How to make UILabel "live"?

Tags: xcode, uilabel, swift3, ios10

I would like to add text to my app so when ever I want to change the text in Xcode, the text will also change for the user. From my understanding so far, if I want to change a UILabel, I would have to submit it to the AppStore again and the user would have to update the app in order to see the UILabel text change.

Is it possible for me to add text on the app when ever I want and it will update for the user automatically?

Comment: Or you could pull the text from a web server or something.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I'm new to this whole code development world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should consider the solution, that will be connecting your app to certain **API service**.

In other words, the service that will bring fresh data to your app, will be an API, that your code will connect to. After connection and getting response from server, data from it will be transferred to the user interface of your application.

For example - your code will be set to make requests from your app using URL, looking like this:

> http://example.com/api/request/?id=100

For better imagination, if you would like to check, what this URL returns, you would type that URL to your browser. It would return some output - for example JSON, something like this:

```
{"label": "This is title"}
```

So your app (after some action, for example when a view is shown or a user taps a button) will establish connection to this URL, to be able to get this output and process it. So it will await some structure, that is needed to read by your program. In this case, the structure is a format of an output, that is JSON.

Then, your code will parse this output and gets result. So the result would be "This is title" and your UILabel would be updated with "This is title".

For URL connections and sessions, using swift3, the best choice to use is an **Alamofire** framework:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

And this is very useful tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/121540/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started.

It explain, how to get an access to a service, that is capable to prepare your output (e.g. JSON), because your app will need to connect to it.
This tutorial is a solid guide, how to create a service like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement web services for this where your app will read data from some server, programmatically. And using this you can update your any type of data. I would suggest to read more about `Objective C` Basic, `Web services`, `AFNNetworking`, `NSURLSession` and all.